# PHP / HTML - re organize array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-lists

I have a array with ID values like this `[2,34,7,46,16,19 ...]` etc

each ID points to more data which I display with html like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    content from 2
    content from 34
    content from 7
  </li>

  <li>
    content from 46
    content from 16
    content from 19
  </li>
  ...
```

notice that in this case there are 3 entries into each list item.
How can share entries from the array to each `<li>` in a such way that there are always exactly 5 list items?

for eg, if the array has 15 items, each `<li>` has 3 items, or if array has 9 items, each `<li>` has at least 1 entry (4 of them will have 2)

Comment: God I love your profile icon. so hilarious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_chunk($myArray, count($myArray) / 5)` should work. You might need to tweak it a little, such as a `ceil` or `floor` on the count/5, but that's the right direction.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php